# Get response Uri from apache HttpResponse and parse it (java)

Tags: java, .net, http, httpresponse

I need to get the response uri from the HttpResponse and parse it into name-value pairs.
I need the analog for the following .NET fragment:

```
string authorizationRequestParameters = string.Format("client_id={0}&response_type=code&scope={1}&access_type=offline", ClientID, Scope);
Uri authorizationRequestUri = new Uri(OauthHost.AbsoluteUri + "?" + authorizationRequestParameters);
HttpWebResponse authorizationResponse = DoGet(authorizationRequestUri, cookies);
NameValueCollection authorizeResponseParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(authorizationResponse.ResponseUri.Query);
string callbackCode = authorizeResponseParameters["code"];
```

The necessary condition is, that in Java version DoGet method returns apache HttpResponse.
The way I tried to do this:

```
HttpResponse resp = hch.doGet("http://...?client_id=...&response_type=...&scope=...&access_type=...");
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
System.out.print(IOUtils.toString(instream, "UTF-8"));
```

I can receive the html-content this way, but I need just response Uri, the part of it, that contains parameters.
How can I do that?

Comment: What is response uri? Is it from HTTP specification? Isn't it the same as request uri?

Comment: This is the URI of the Internet resource that responded to the request. In my case, that's the URI I was redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property comes from either a `Content-Location` header or it is a request `URI`. So something like this should work:

```
final String uri = "http://...?client_id=...&response_type=...&scope=...&access_type=...";
final HttpResponse resp = hch.doGet(uri);
final String contentLocation = resp.getFirstHeader ("Content-Location");
final String responseURI = contentLocation != null ? contentLocation : uri;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. resp.getFirstHeader ("Content-Location"); always contains null, but I'm redirected when I get access to the same resource form the browser.